# UDP Broadcast: Motorola block incoming ports?

Tags: android, udp, broadcast

I've created a library for **sending** and **receiving** **UDP broadcasts** using a WiFi network, and my code works fine, I tried it using a **Nexus 5** and a **Samsung Galaxy S2** and the communication works great, they both send and receive.

When I try my same code with a **Moto G**, the device can send packages to other phones, but **can't receive** anything. I can blame the Moto G because the code works great in other two devices and they both can receive the packages that the Moto G sends. I even tried two different Moto G, one stock and one rooted with specific firewall policies.

I tried using different ports, not many honestly, but I guess the problem is not there.

Any clues what could be wrong?

Android versions for each device:
Nexus 5: 4.5
S2: 4.1.2
Moto G 1: 4.4.2
Moto G 2: 4.4.1 (not sure)

I'm targeting SDK 16. My [code is here](https://github.com/fabriph/some-android-apps/tree/master/UDPBroadcast).

Comment: I tried with Moto G second generation and I couldn't receive. As mentioned it sends data but can't receive. However it receives packet sent to loopback ("127.0.0.1") within app. Quite annoying.

Comment: Check solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838660/moto-g-dosent-receive-udp-packets-over-wifi-network

Comment: I noticed that If I set up a mobile AP with the Moto G as the source of the AP, then the Moto G get to send data, and also receive. So If I connect my Nexus 5 to the AP of the Moto G, both phones will be able to send and receive.

Answer (score 2):

My Moto G (4.4.4) shows the same problem. Sending UDP-packets works, but receiving UDP-packets does not. I found several websites describing the same problem for several other vendors.

**Workaround:**
I solved the problem for my Moto G, by using MulticastSocket (instead of DatagramSocket) with TTL=1 and IP=224.0.0.1.

Comment: This also helped me with a Redmi Note. Changing to Multicast Socket

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `MulticastSocket` for receiving instead of `DatagramSocket`.
2. Send broadcast message to multicast address `(224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255`)

## Sender

```
final String ip = "224.0.0.3";
final int port = 8091;
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg,msg.length, InetAddress.getByName(ip),port);
socket.send(packet);
```

## Receiver

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(8091);
socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.3"));
byte[] data = new byte[4096];
while(!stop){
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
}
```