# Moto G dosent receive UDP packets over WIFI Network

Tags: android, udp

My receiver don't receive any UDP packet in Moto G but it works for other devices well.

Over WiFi network I have send UDP packets successfully from other devices. But in Moto E and Moto G it is not working.

Can anyone help figure out why it's not working for Moto G/E?

My problem was that i was not Receiving any UDP Packets over WiFi Network.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It's work for me.

```
 public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        try {
          WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
          WifiManager wifi;

          wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          if (lock == null)
          lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("WiFi_Lock");
          lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
          lock.acquire();
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        Log.d("Wifi Exception",""+e.getMessage().toString());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the exact same problem! UDP packets would work on every phone except the Moto E. Then I found some very interesting information on the [interwebz](http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/).

The problem was that the Moto E (and presumably the Moto G) requires the app to acquire `WifiManager.MulticastLock`. From the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html) -

> Allows an application to receive Wifi Multicast packets. Normally the
>   Wifi stack filters out packets not explicitly addressed to this
>   device. Acquring a MulticastLock will cause the stack to receive
>   packets addressed to multicast addresses. Processing these extra
>   packets can cause a noticable battery drain and should be disabled
>   when not needed.

You need to add the following permission to your app -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

And then in your code acquire a lock like so -

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );
if(wifi != null){
    WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("Log_Tag");
    lock.acquire();
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me. Actually when setting up server for listening, one doesn't have to specify nothing about the wifi service, example: https://github.com/fabriph/some-android-apps/blob/master/UDPBroadcast/src/com/fabriph/udpbroadcast/UDPServer.java

Comment: How did you embed your answer into a receiving socket? As far as I know, the service is needed for sending the broadcast, but for listening you have a regular socket.