# UDP broadcast in Android doesn't work with all devices

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

The scenario is simple: I have two smartphones **A** and **B**. **A** broadcasts UDP messages with a certain frequency (e.g. one per minute), while **B** listens and captures these packets.
Both devices are connected to the same WiFi local network and can ping each other.

### Working scenario

When I use these two devices everything works as expected:

- Device A (sender): Sony Xperia Z5, Android 6.0.1.
- Device B (receiver): Xiaomi Mi 4S, Android 5.1.1.

I can see that the device B receives the UDP messages correctly.

### Not working scenario

Then, I replace the receiver device B with a Motorola Moto G, 1st generation, Android 5.1. The Motorola phone doesn't receive the packets.
Using Wireshark I can see that A keeps sending the packets as before.

This is the code I use for sending:

```
private class D2DBroadcastThread implements Runnable {
public void run() {
  Log.i(TAG, "Running the broadcast message runnable");
  if (context == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Context is null!!!");
  }
  broadcastMessage(new D2DMessage(context, D2DMessage.MsgType.HELLO));
  mBroadcastHandler.postDelayed(mBroadcastRunnable, Constants.D2D_BROADCAST_INTERVAL);
}

private void broadcastMessage(final D2DMessage msg) {
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      DatagramPacket packet;
      MulticastSocket socket = null;
      try {
        byte[] data = Utils.objectToByteArray(msg);

        socket = new MulticastSocket(Constants.D2D_BROADCAST_PORT);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);

        InetAddress myIpAddress = Utils.getIpAddress();
        if (myIpAddress != null) {
          Log.i(TAG, "My IP address: " + myIpAddress.getHostAddress());

          InetAddress broadcastAddress = Utils.getBroadcast(myIpAddress);
          Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast IP address: " + broadcastAddress);
          try {
            packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, broadcastAddress,
                Constants.D2D_BROADCAST_PORT);
            socket.send(packet);
            Log.i(TAG, "==>> Broadcast message sent to " + broadcastAddress);
            Log.i(TAG, "==>> CMD: " + msg);

          } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending data: " + e);
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending data: " + e);
      } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
          socket.close();
        }
      }
    }
  }.start();
}
}
```

And this is the code I use for receiving:

```
  receiveSocket = new MulticastSocket(Constants.D2D_BROADCAST_PORT);
  receiveSocket.setBroadcast(true);
  Log.i(TAG, "Started listening on multicast socket.");

  try {
    while (true) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for broadcasted data...");
      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
      receiveSocket.receive(packet);
      Log.d(TAG, "Received a new broadcast packet from: " + packet.getAddress());
      processPacket(packet);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The socket was closed.");
  }
```

Comment: What did you get in the output/stack trace ?

Comment: Nothing, the packets are not received at all on this second device. This device just keeps listening as if nothing happened.

Comment: There should be something, if it is working on one device and not working on another that doesn't make sense until there is some problem on the receiving end which is always shown in Log consoles.

Comment: That's why I am getting frustrated, since it works perfectly with the other device but not with this one. I hoped maybe someone was aware of any known issue about UDP broadcasting on specific devices.

Comment: Well, was searching for your problem and came to a solution, it seems that Motorola blocks some UDP ports, look at the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31625932/1061944

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, even though I'm already using MulticastSocket. I will try again when I'm on my developing machine.

Comment: And this one too http://stackoverflow.com/a/30708329/1061944

Comment: The second link did the trick for me actually. Now it works also on the Motorola Moto G phone.